# Cython - copy constructors

Tags: cython

I've got a C library that I'm trying to wrap in Cython. One of the classes I'm creating contains a pointer to a C structure. I'd like to write a copy constructor that would create a second Python object pointing to the same C structure, but I'm having trouble, as the pointer cannot be converted into a python object.

Here's a sketch of what I'd like to have:

```
cdef class StructName:
     cdef c_libname.StructName* __structname

     def __cinit__(self, other = None):
         if not other:
             self.__structname = c_libname.constructStructName()
         elif type(other) is StructName:
             self.__structname = other.__structname
```

The real problem is that last line - it seems Cython can't access cdef fields from within a python method. I've tried writing an accessor method, with the same result. How can I create a copy constructor in this situation?

Comment: Your question title is not very specific, can you please make it a bit more detailed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When playing with `cdef` classes, attribute access are compiled to C struct member access. As a consequence, to access to a `cdef` member of an object `A` you have to be sure of the type of `A`. In `__cinit__` you didn't tell Cython that other is an instance of `StructName`. Therefore Cython refuses to compile `other.__structname`. To fix the problem, just write

```
def __cinit__(self, StructName other = None):
```

Note: `None` is equivalent to `NULL` and therefore is accepted as a `StructName`.

If you want more polymorphism then you have to rely on type casts:

```
 def __cinit__(self, other = None):
     cdef StructName ostr
     if not other:
         self.__structname = c_libname.constructStructName()
     elif type(other) is StructName:
         ostr = <StructName> other
         self.__structname = ostr.__structname
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd tried casting earlier, but I put the type definition 'cdef StructName ostr' in the elif block, and it didn't compile. I assumed that meant I couldn't use cdef within python methods. Do you happen to know why that wouldn't have worked?

Comment: Python and C/C++ scoping rules are very different. As a consequence, the Cython developers decided that all `cdef` declaration must be done at the beginning of the function.

Comment: I just made a Q&A question about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572718/why-cython-forces-declaration-of-locals-at-the-beginning-of-a-function/21572719#21572719